# Elements from a list to be removed that have a 'specific number of characters'

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I currently have a list such as:

```
list1 = ['123', '1bc', 'a', 'Machine Learning', '', '7', 'is', '', 'c', 'data science', '', 'python']
```

How do I change it into a list having elements that has more than 1 character, such as

```
['123', '1bc', 'Machine Learning', 'is', 'data science', 'python']
```

that is, it should be removing all the elements that has 1 or less than 1 character.

My actual current list is something like this:

```
l = ['1', '00:00:05,849 --> 00:00:13,730', 'abdomen', '', '2', '00:00:13,740 --> 00:00:21,269', 'afghan', '', '3', '00:00:21,269 --> 00:00:27,989', 'albic', '', '4', '00:00:27,989 --> 00:00:36,085', 'dug desert']
```

I want to keep only the elements that have timestamps and its corresponding text. I want to remove everything else. To do so, the easiest way would be to remove the elements with characters 1 or less than 1, right? Because that's what all the remaining elements that are to be removed are.

Comment: `[x for x in list1 if len(x)>1]`?

Comment: @harshita-m-u as much as we want to give you want you are looking for, we also want to see what you tried to see what did not work for you.

Comment: `l=list(filter(lambda i:len(i)>1,l))` will do the needful but where are the timestamps or what are you calling timestamps. i dont see anything which resembles a timestamp in your list???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [List Comprehensions:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) with len

```
print([el for el in ist1 if len (el) > 1])
```

sample output

```
['123', '1bc', 'Machine Learning', 'is', 'data science', 'python']
```